# How to add query to classroom API request?

Tags: swift, api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-classroom

I am currently requesting for the coursework of a student using the classroom API using the following code:

```
self.oauthswift!.client.get("https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/\(id)/courseWork?access_token=\(access)") { result in
                 switch result {
                    case .success(let response):
```

Through this code I get all the assignments as requested. However, they are in random order. I need them sorted by due date. I know I can do this using a query, but I have no idea where to add the query in the https request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the query parameter `orderBy` in order to sort the listed courseWork via `updateTime` or `dueDate`, as you can see on the [method documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list). You'd just need to add this parameter to the requested URL, like this:

```
https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/\(id)/courseWork?orderBy=dueDate&access_token=\(access)
```

By default, the listed courseWork are sorted in descending order. To make it ascending, use `dueDate asc` instead. So in this case, the URL would be:

```
https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/\(id)/courseWork?orderBy=dueDate%20asc&access_token=\(access)
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: courses.courseWork.list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork/list)